# Azure: Can't Deploy FortiGate from ARM - Error "The 'unknown' payment instrument(s) is not supported for offer..."

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace, fortigate

This is my exact error:

> {"code":"MarketplacePurchaseEligibilityFailed","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Offer with PublisherId: 'fortinet', OfferId: 'fortinet_fortigate-vm_v5' cannot be purchased due to validation errors. For more information see details. Correlation Id: '1974016a-705c-44d4-b2ad-d79a8766a1b6' The 'unknown' payment instrument(s) is not supported for offer with OfferId: 'fortinet_fortigate-vm_v5', PlanId 'fortinet_fg-vm_payg_20190624'. Correlation Id '1974016a-705c-44d4-b2ad-d79a8766a1b6'.[{"The 'unknown' payment instrument(s) is not supported for offer with OfferId: 'fortinet_fortigate-vm_v5', PlanId 'fortinet_fg-vm_payg_20190624'. Correlation Id '1974016a-705c-44d4-b2ad-d79a8766a1b6'.":"StoreApi"}]"},{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Offer with PublisherId: 'fortinet', OfferId: 'fortinet_fortigate-vm_v5' cannot be purchased due to validation errors. For more information see details. Correlation Id: '1974016a-705c-44d4-b2ad-d79a8766a1b6' The 'unknown' payment instrument(s) is not supported for offer with OfferId: 'fortinet_fortigate-vm_v5', PlanId 'fortinet_fg-vm_payg_20190624'. Correlation Id '1974016a-705c-44d4-b2ad-d79a8766a1b6'.[{"The 'unknown' payment instrument(s) is not supported for offer with OfferId: 'fortinet_fortigate-vm_v5', PlanId 'fortinet_fg-vm_payg_20190624'. Correlation Id '1974016a-705c-44d4-b2ad-d79a8766a1b6'.":"StoreApi"}]"}],"message":"Marketplace purchase eligibilty check returned errors. See inner errors for details. "}

I'm using an MPN account with plenty of credit, I presume that's my issue but not sure why? If I've got credit I should be able to buy what I want surely?

Answer (score 3):

It is the MPN subscription, this page shows that it's limited in scope sadly: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/offers/ms-azr-0029p/

[image]